# Agregar Propiedad

Tags: javascript

```
function agregaPropiedad(amigos, propiedad) {
```

// La funcion llamada 'agregaPropiedad' recibe como argumento un array llamado 'amigos' que contiene

// en cada posición del arreglo un objeto que puede tener como propiedades 'nombre' o 'edad'. También

// recibe un string llamado 'propiedad'.

// Esta funcion debe agregar la propiedad 'propiedad' y setearla en null a aquellos objetos dentro de
'amigos' que no tengan esa propiedad

// Debe devolver el array 'amigos' modificado.

// Nota: Si el objeto dentro de 'amigos' tiene esa 'propiedad' no modificarla.

// Ej:

// var amigos = [{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];
// agregaPropiedad(amigos, 'edad') debe devolver [{ nombre: 'toni', edad: null } , { nombre: 'Emi', ed
ad: 25 }]

Mi código es:

```
array.forEach(function (item) {
    if (!item.hasOwnProperty(propiedad)) {
        item[propiedad] = null; 
    }
  })
  
  return array;
}
```

Me gustaría saber que esta mal y como podría resolverlo.

Error que da el test.

```
● Funciones › agregaPropiedad › should return "[{ nombre: "toni", edad: null }, { nombre: "Emi", edad: 25 }]"

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: [{"edad": null, "nombre": "toni"}, {"edad": 25, "nombre": "Emi"}]
    Received: undefined

      100 | 
      101 |     it('should return "[{ nombre: "toni", edad: null }, { nombre: "Emi", edad: 25 }]"', function() {
    > 102 |       expect(agregaPropiedad([{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }], 'edad')).toEqual([{ nombre: "toni", edad: null }, { nombre: "Emi", edad: 25 }]);
          |                                                                                           ^
      103 |     });
      104 |     it('should return "[{ nombre: "toni" }, { nombre: "Emi", edad: 25 }]"', function() {
      105 |       expect(agregaPropiedad([{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }], 'nombre')).toEqual([{ nombre: "toni" }, { nombre: "Emi", edad: 25 }]);

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/checkpoint.test.js:102:91)

  ● Funciones › agregaPropiedad › should return "[{ nombre: "toni" }, { nombre: "Emi", edad: 25 }]"

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: [{"nombre": "toni"}, {"edad": 25, "nombre": "Emi"}]
    Received: undefined

      103 |     });
      104 |     it('should return "[{ nombre: "toni" }, { nombre: "Emi", edad: 25 }]"', function() {
    > 105 |       expect(agregaPropiedad([{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }], 'nombre')).toEqual([{ nombre: "toni" }, { nombre: "Emi", edad: 25 }]);
          |                                                                                             ^
      106 |     });
      107 |   });
```

Comment: ¿Obtienes algún error? De ser así, no olvides compartirlo. Otra observación, según la descripción y la definición de tu función, el array se llama `amigos` pero en el foreach usas `array`, el cual no está definido en nunguna parte.

Comment: Hola @ricardo-dlc al final de la publicación pongo el error que me da el test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente el único error que veo en tu código, es el *typo* que te mencioné en el comentario. Adicionalmente renombré algunas variables para que sea un poco más amigable de leer y que puedas ver lo que sucede en cada parte del código.

```js
function agregaPropiedad(amigos, propiedad) {
  amigos.forEach(amigo => {
    if (!amigo.hasOwnProperty(propiedad)) {
      amigo[propiedad] = null; 
    }
  });
  
  return amigos;
}

console.log(agregaPropiedad([{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }], 'edad'));

console.log(agregaPropiedad([{ nombre: 'toni' } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }], 'nombre'));
```

Si `amigo` no tiene la propiedad `propiedad`, entonces entrará en la sentencia if y establecerá la propiedad `propiedad` a `amigo`. Si la tiene, simplemente no hará nada. Al finalizar, retornar el array `amigos`.

He probado con los dos errores que muestras y la salida parece ser la esperada.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió